# CUDA installation, uncomprehensible conflicts

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

**SOLVED**, the initial question and all of the error messages and attempts are below.

For those visiting this page in the future:

- the accepted answer worked after all of the attempts I made and that you need to reconstruct from the comments
- **After the installation** as indicated in the accepted answer, I had a problem with nvcc, that stayed at version 10.1. In order to get the most recent version (or the one corresponding to the CUDA version you installed) **REMEMBER TO PERFORM THE MANDATORY [POST-INSTALLATION ACTIONS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions).**

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION AND ATTEMPTS SUGGESTED IN THE COMMENTS**

Yesterday, my Ubuntu 20.04 machine realized it had CUDA conflicts. I was not able to fix them, so I decided to uninstall it using the instruction on the [nvidia web-site](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions) :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove <package_name>          # Ubuntu
```

it is possible that I made some wrong choices, but I couldn't tell which.

Then I followed the instructions [here, for Ubuntu](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions). I ended up on this [page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local) and followed the instructions.

Here it is what I have:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-11-6 (>= 11.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-11-6 (>= 11.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-runtime-11-6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-runtime-11-6 : Depends: cuda-drivers (>= 510.39.01) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: cuda-drivers-510 (= 510.47.03-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers-510
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-510 : Depends: nvidia-driver-510 (>= 510.47.03) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-510
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-510 : Depends: nvidia-dkms-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1)
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-compute-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-510:i386 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-dkms-510
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-dkms-510 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-510 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-510 (= 510.47.03-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and so on.

I am not a system manager: I just need to install nvidia on this linux machine. I promise I made quite a lot of web searches, but cannot find a source with clear and working instructions.

Is there anyone who is able to understand the reason of this mess and can suggest a solution/web page with clear instructions? I would rather not re-install the OS, let me know if that is the only solution.

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions

---

As requested in the comments:

```
ls -al /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
4 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 190 Jun 29  2020 /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
Package: nsight-compute
Pin: origin *ubuntu.com*
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: nsight-systems
Pin: origin *ubuntu.com*
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: *
Pin: release l=NVIDIA CUDA
Pin-Priority: 600

apt-cache policy cuda cuda-drivers nvidia-dkms-510 
cuda:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.6.0-1
  Version table:
     11.6.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Packages
     11.5.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.5.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.5.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.4-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.3-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.4.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.3.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Packages
     11.3.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.2.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.1.1-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.1.0-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.0.3-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     11.0.2-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
cuda-drivers:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 510.47.03-1
  Version table:
     510.47.03-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     510.39.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Packages
     495.29.05-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     470.103.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     470.82.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     470.57.02-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     470.42.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     465.19.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Packages
     460.106.00-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     460.91.03-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     460.73.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     460.32.03-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     460.27.04-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     455.45.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     455.32.00-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     455.23.05-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.172.01-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.156.00-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.142.00-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.119.04-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.119.03-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.102.04-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.80.02-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.51.06-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     450.51.05-1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
nvidia-dkms-510:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 510.47.03-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     510.47.03-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
     510.47.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     510.39.01-0ubuntu1 600
        600 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  Packages
        600 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local  Packages
```

Output of: `ls -al /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-6-local/`

```
4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      1633 Jan 11 07:07 7fa2af80.pub
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2394 Jan 11 07:07 cuda_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2448 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
  1020 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1040544 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cccl-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2464 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-command-line-tools-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
 15044 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  15403332 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-compat-11-6_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2428 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-compiler-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
   160 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    160604 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cudart-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
   740 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    753790 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cudart-dev-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
   116 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    115138 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cuobjdump-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
 12752 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  13054952 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cupti-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
  2444 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   2500758 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cupti-dev-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
   184 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    188182 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-cuxxfilt-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
  3888 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   3977988 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-demo-suite-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
    52 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     49872 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-documentation-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
    28 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     27070 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-driver-dev-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2500 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-drivers_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2616 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-drivers-510_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      3170 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-drivers-fabricmanager_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      3206 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-510_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
  4008 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   4103954 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-gdb-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
 58716 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  60123814 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-gdb-src-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2508 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-libraries-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2530 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-libraries-dev-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
   140 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    142296 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-memcheck-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2440 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-minimal-build-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
115832 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 118608806 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nsight-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      3706 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nsight-compute-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      3306 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nsight-systems-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
 34948 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  35785836 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvcc-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
 32044 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  32809456 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvdisasm-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
    76 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     77328 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvml-dev-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
  1904 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1946136 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvprof-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
    60 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     57516 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvprune-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
 14628 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  14978358 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvrtc-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
 73704 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  75471468 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
    52 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     51380 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvtx-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
109924 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 112555442 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-nvvp-11-6_11.6.58-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2426 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-runtime-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
    16 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     16288 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-samples-11-6_11.6.101-1_amd64.deb
  8328 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   8527458 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-sanitizer-11-6_11.6.55-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      3372 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-toolkit-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
    16 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     16308 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-toolkit-11-6-config-common_11.6.55-1_all.deb
    16 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     16342 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-toolkit-11-config-common_11.6.55-1_all.deb
    16 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     16330 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-toolkit-config-common_11.6.55-1_all.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2390 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-tools-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       190 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2868 Jan 11 07:07 cuda-visual-tools-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
 37980 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  38890708 Jan 11 07:07 gds-tools-11-6_1.2.0.100-1_amd64.deb
210464 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 215509372 Jan 11 07:07 libcublas-11-6_11.8.1.74-1_amd64.deb
214852 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 220001236 Jan 11 07:07 libcublas-dev-11-6_11.8.1.74-1_amd64.deb
 66720 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  68320046 Jan 11 07:07 libcufft-11-6_10.7.0.55-1_amd64.deb
148744 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 152311988 Jan 11 07:07 libcufft-dev-11-6_10.7.0.55-1_amd64.deb
   456 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    466618 Jan 11 07:07 libcufile-11-6_1.2.0.100-1_amd64.deb
  7516 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   7693178 Jan 11 07:07 libcufile-dev-11-6_1.2.0.100-1_amd64.deb
 40568 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  41540444 Jan 11 07:07 libcurand-11-6_10.2.9.55-1_amd64.deb
 40896 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  41876588 Jan 11 07:07 libcurand-dev-11-6_10.2.9.55-1_amd64.deb
 46640 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  47753052 Jan 11 07:07 libcusolver-11-6_11.3.2.55-1_amd64.deb
 30376 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  31103978 Jan 11 07:07 libcusolver-dev-11-6_11.3.2.55-1_amd64.deb
 96244 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  98547234 Jan 11 07:07 libcusparse-11-6_11.7.1.55-1_amd64.deb
 96376 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  98683226 Jan 11 07:07 libcusparse-dev-11-6_11.7.1.55-1_amd64.deb
 80636 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  82565404 Jan 11 07:07 libnpp-11-6_11.6.0.55-1_amd64.deb
 79012 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  80907982 Jan 11 07:07 libnpp-dev-11-6_11.6.0.55-1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-cfg1-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    80 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     79374 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-cfg1-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6892 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-common-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_all.deb
    12 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     10276 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-common-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_all.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6904 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-compute-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-compute-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
 30704 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  31438322 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-compute-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 24524 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  25112298 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-compute-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-decode-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-decode-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
  1224 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1251804 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-decode-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  1208 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1236212 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-decode-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-encode-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-encode-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
    44 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     41762 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-encode-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    44 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     44674 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-encode-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
    48 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     49118 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-extra-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    52 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     53154 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-extra-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-fbc1-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-fbc1-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
    48 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     46886 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-fbc1-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    52 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     50298 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-fbc1-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6896 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-gl-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6896 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-gl-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
164588 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 168530546 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-gl-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 22460 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  22998738 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-gl-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
   316 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    319502 Jan 11 07:07 libnvidia-nscq-510_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
  1764 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1803794 Jan 11 07:07 libnvjpeg-11-6_11.6.0.55-1_amd64.deb
  1444 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1477650 Jan 11 07:07 libnvjpeg-dev-11-6_11.6.0.55-1_amd64.deb
    24 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     21438 Jan 11 07:07 libxnvctrl0_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    92 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     93926 Jan 11 07:07 libxnvctrl-dev_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
402492 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 412144910 Jan 11 07:07 nsight-compute-2022.1.0_2022.1.0.12-1_amd64.deb
231040 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 236577286 Jan 11 07:07 nsight-systems-2021.5.2_2021.5.2.53-1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6904 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-compute-utils-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   344 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    351076 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-compute-utils-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6892 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-dkms-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    32 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     29510 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-dkms-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6888 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-driver-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   432 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    442116 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-driver-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  1360 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1390720 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-fabricmanager-510_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
   352 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    356628 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-fabricmanager-dev-510_510.39.01-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2446 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-fs_2.10.3-1_amd64.deb
    72 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     73328 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-fs-dkms_2.10.3-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2388 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-gds_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      2440 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-gds-11-6_11.6.0-1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6896 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-headless-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6996 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-headless-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6916 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      7124 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-headless-no-dkms-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6900 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-kernel-common-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 19992 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  20468134 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-kernel-common-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6904 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-kernel-source-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 28468 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  29147678 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-kernel-source-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    20 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     20030 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-modprobe_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   912 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    931288 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-settings_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6896 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-utils-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   380 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    385654 Jan 11 07:07 nvidia-utils-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
    36 -rw-r--r--  1 root root     34404 Jan 11 07:07 Packages.gz
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       564 Jan 11 07:07 Release
     4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root       836 Jan 11 07:07 Release.gpg
     8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root      6920 Jan 11 07:07 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
  1364 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   1396120 Jan 11 07:07 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-510_510.39.01-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

```
dpkg -l *nvidia*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version            Architecture Description
+++-================================-==================-============-=======================================================
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia            <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-compute-510:i386       510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
un  libnvidia-decode                 <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-decode-510:i386        510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
un  libnvidia-encode                 <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-encode-510:i386        510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
un  libnvidia-fbc1                   <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386          510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
un  libnvidia-ml1                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-prime                     <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134147/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-sesto-cuda-installation-uncomprehensible-conf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Confirm that **Secure Boot** is disabled in your BIOS.
- `dpkg -l *nvidia*` shows that no Nvidia software was installed.
- Confirm that `dkms status` shows no leftover Nvidia kernel modules:

---

```
nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
```

---

If there are any, we'll have to `dkms remove` them:

`sudo dkms remove nvidia/510.47.03 -k 5.13.0-28-generic`

- We'll clean up an purge these leftover packages:

---

```
ii  libnvidia-compute-510:i386       510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-510:i386        510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-510:i386        510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-510:i386          510.47.03-0ubuntu1 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
```

`sudo apt purge package_name`

- Open **Additional Drivers**
- Select the **noveau** driver and reboot.
- Select Nvidia 510 (tested, proprietary) driver and reboot.
- In **terminal** type `nvidia-smi`
- Download and install CUDA 11.6. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local
- Reboot

Comment: I purged the packages, the 510 drivers were installed and in use. Indeed the dkms command returns nvidia, 510.47.03, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed . What should I remove?

Comment: @AntonioSesto I updated my answer with the `dkms remove` command you'll need.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Show me `dpkg -l *cuda*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you ever happen to come to Italy call me and I will buy you a beer.

Comment: @AntonioSesto Are you working ok now? You disappeared yesterday right in the middle our working on this yesterday... what happened?

Comment: Sorry for yesterday, but I had an unexpected meeting here at work and went away as soon as it finished (20:30): I should have come back to tell you. I am very sorry about that but I was really tired and willing to go home. Thanks again, to you and to all who have helped.

Comment: Great answer, I find this problem very often. BTW, you can check if secure boot is disabled with `mokutil --sb-state`